# Notice Array to string conversion using nusoap

Tags: php, web-services, nusoap

I'm developing a web service in PHP, using nosoap. this is my file, webservice.php

```
<?php
require_once "nusoap/nusoap.php";

$namespace = "urn:mywsdl";
$server = new soap_server();
$server->configureWSDL('myWS', $namespace);
$server->wsdl->schemaTargetNamespace = $namespace;

$server->wsdl->addComplexType('datosBasicos', 'complexType', 'struct', 'all', '', array(
    'codigo' => array(
        'name' => 'codigo',
        'type' => 'xsd:string'
    ),
    'nombre' => array(
        'name' => 'nombre',
        'type' => 'xsd:string'
    )
));


$server->wsdl->addComplexType('arraydatosBasicos', 'complexType', 'array', '', 'SOAP-ENC:Array', array(), array(
    array('ref' => 'SOAP-ENC:arrayType',
        'wsdl:arrayType' => 'tns:datosBasicos[]')
        ), 'tns:datosBasicos'
);


$server->register('saludar', array('nombre' => 'xsd:string'), array('return' => 'tns:arraydatosBasicos'), $namespace);

function saludar($nombre) {
    $array[] = array('codigo' => '123', 'nombre' => 'test');
    $array[] = array('codigo' => '5745', 'nombre' => 'probando');
    $datos[] = $array[1];
    return $datos;
}

$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);
?>
```

But, when I deploy the web service, with SOAPUI, I get this error:

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\nusoap\nusoap\nusoap.php</b> on line <b>6132</b><br />
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got a similar error, I had to comment a line in nusoap.php..something like:

```
//$this->debug("$k = $v<br>");
```

and it was fine for me.

Obviously, it is only for debug so don't worry about the functionality, because it should be the same if you comment the line. I think when you create complex data (that's mean, in your case an array inside another array)
nusoap is not able to print it for debugging.

Anyway good luck.

Comment: in newer nusoap version it is: $this->debug("serializing array element: $k, $v of type: $typeDef[arrayType]"); in line 6132

Comment: Thanks @user3980820 your solution solved! i was digging this from past several days!! :'-D

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem. You can convert the data to string to keep the debug for further usage and remove the warning

Search for this code

```
foreach(curl_getinfo($this->ch) as $k => $v){
    $err .= "$k: $v<br>";
}
$this->debug($err);
```

And replace with this one

```
foreach(curl_getinfo($this->ch) as $k => $v){
    if(is_array($v)){
        $v = implode(" / ", $v);
    }
    $err .= "$k: $v<br>";
}
$this->debug($err);
```

Answer (score 1):

For latest nuSoap version, the below will solve your problem :

FIND the below code in nusoap.php

```
$this->debug("serializing array element: $k, $v of type: $typeDef[arrayType]");
```

in line 6132 or something around this no.

AND COMMENT IT

```
// $this->debug("serializing array element: $k, $v of type: $typeDef[arrayType]");
```

Since it just for debug purpose. so not to worry about any functionality issues.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem in nusoap-0.9.5 (for php5.3) and the error was occurring due to some server header being passed as blank array.
So, I have added the following code and found it's working fine now.

```
if(is_array($v))
{
    $v = implode(",", $v );
}
```