# PHP: Return Array of Custom Objects with NuSoap WebService

Tags: php, web-services, soap, nusoap

I have created the following custom class in PHP:

```
<?php

class myClass
{
   public $property1;
   public $property2;
}
?>
```

I have a NuSoap Webservice that I want to use to return an array of these objects in XML format.  I have built the following function to return the data:

```
foreach($response->return->object as $object)
        {
            $returnObject = new $myClass;
            $returnObject->property1 = $object->property1;
            $returnObject->property2 = $object->property2;
            array_push($returnObjects, $returnObject);
        }
    }
    $result = array_unique($returnObjects);
    if (count($result) != 0){
    return $result;}
```

When I run the method, I get the following error:

> Object of class MyClass could not be converted to string

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This post ended up being my solution:

[Notice Array to string conversion using nusoap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22482881/notice-array-to-string-conversion-using-nusoap)

Evidently there is a debugging conversion that breaks when you use complex data types.  Luckily line 6132 can be commented out in the NuSoap.php without causing any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Object creation is wrong.

```
$returnObject = new $myClass;
```

change above line to following

```
$returnObject = new myClass();
```

Comment: In the process of obfuscation this was a type-o. I actually had "new myClass" without the dollar sign.  I changed it to your suggestion and there was no change in the result.